# I meet a trouble about hash in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a trouble about hash in rails

**example:**

```
grades = {"a" => 10, "b" => 6}
grades = {"c"=>15, "d"=>16}

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: grades }
end
```

but result is received  : `"c"=>15, d"=>16`

why doesn't it return all :  `a,b,c,d.`

Comment: for i in 0...2 do

      records['data'] = [
          @items_record[i]['id'],
          @items_record[i]['stauts'],
          @items_record[i]['name_vi'],
      ]

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: records }
    end

Answer (score 4):

You are overriding your variable. You need either do:

```
grades = { "a" => 10, "b" => 6 }
grades.merge!({"c"=>15, "d"=>16})
```

or

```
grades = { "a" => 10, "b" => 6 }
grades['c'] = 15
greade['d'] = 16
```

for your 2nd problem in the comment:

I guess you want something like this:

```
records['data'] = []
(0..2).each do |i|
  records['data'] << [@items_record[i]['id'], @items_record[i]['id'], @items_record[i]['name_vi']]
end
```

Comment: for i in 0...2 do

      records['data'] = [
          @items_record[i]['id'],
          @items_record[i]['stauts'],
          @items_record[i]['name_vi'],
      ]

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: records }
    end

Comment: what are you trying to tell me with that random code?

Comment: for i in 0...2 do

      
      records['data'] = [
          @items_record[i]['id'],
          @items_record[i]['id'],
          @items_record[i]['name_vi'],
      ]


    end

but my result is : {"data":[2,2,"Tuyển dụng"],"draw":1,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2}
i wish my received is : {"data":[2,2,"Tuyển dụng"],[2,2,"Tuyển dụng"],"draw":1,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2}

Comment: so you want records['data'] to be an array of arrays?

Comment: {"data":[["14","a","1"],["15","DeliveryInformation"],"2"],"draw":1,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2}

Comment: records['data'] << [@items_record[i]['id'], @items_record[i]['id'], @items_record[i]['name_vi']] is not working i received error

Comment: well since you seem unable to describe your error, i am done helping

Comment: i copy this code : records['data'] = []
(0..2).each do |i|
  records['data'] << [@items_record[i]['id'], @items_record[i]['id'], @items_record[i]['name_vi']]
end but i received errror